# How to keep the 2D sprite within the screen from the following code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was looking to keep the 2d sprite within the screen not go over it.I have created a square sprite as my player and dragged and dropped the following script which works for the movement of the player on x and y axis.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

private float moveSpeed = 10f;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    MovePlayer();

}

private void MovePlayer()
{
    float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    horizontalMovement = horizontalMovement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    horizontalMovement += transform.position.x;

    verticalMovement = verticalMovement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    verticalMovement += transform.position.y;

    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(horizontalMovement, verticalMovement);
    transform.position = movement;


}
}
```

When I try to clamp the player(square) within the screen problem arises(script given below).I created another script for clamping the sprite.The square is blinking between left lower screen and right top screen.It is trying to move between two ends.It is because I am getting two position(x and y) and giving its position to the square.But I want to make sure the player does not go beyond the screen bounds.

```
public class ScreenBoundary : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject square;
protected Vector3 screenbounds;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    screenbounds = GetScreenBoundary();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 viewPosition = square.transform.position;
    viewPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewPosition.x, screenbounds.x, screenbounds.x * -1);
    viewPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(viewPosition.y, screenbounds.y, screenbounds.y * -1);
    square.transform.position = viewPosition;

}

private Vector3 GetScreenBoundary()
{
    Camera mainCamera = Camera.main;
    Vector3 screenVector = new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, mainCamera.transform.position.z);
    return mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenVector);
}
}
```

How to use the above two scripts to keep the sprite within the screen bounds?

Comment: Make sure the camera is facing +Z direction

Comment: Yes it is..but the issue here is different  I think.

Comment: You could transfer the squares position to screen space before clamping it (Camera.WorldToScreenPoint) since you are using a screen bounds which are in screen space, and then returning it back to world space and setting the boxes position then :D